# Get PCA datapoints in R

Tags: r, ggbiplot

I am using the [following example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/) to test my data in pca.

I was hoping to extract the data points used to plot PCA scatter chart with ggbiplot function. I couldnt find anything in ggbiplot documentation, but maybe someone is aware of an alternative ?

Thank you

Comment: the PCs are in `ir.pca$rotation` `str` is your friend in these cases to inspect what is in a object.

Comment: @emilliman5 thanks for suggestion, as you recommended I have used rotation command and this is my output [here](https://img42.com/ERSfm). Could you please comment on it ? As far as I understand I see the vector values but not the x&y for the end scatter chat.

Comment: The x and y are PC1 and PC2 in this case. Normally, PCA the first few components are the ones we care about since they capture the mist variation

Comment: @emilliman5 understood, but if thats the case, why is the function (ir.pca$rotation) only returning 4 points in the plot ? There are quite a few points in the scatter chart in the end result...

Answer (score 0):

The ir.pca object has several properties, and one of them is "x", which had all the points I was looking for.

[This](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/principal-component-analysis-in-r-prcomp-vs-princomp-r-software-and-data-mining) was what led me to an answer.